# MVC 2 Validation without BuddyClasses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using asp.NET MVC 2 for my current project and I need to validate form fields both on client and server side. For that I started with DataAnnotations.

Now, I figure out that I have to write buddy class for every model or I have to go to designer generated code and put my annotations there (not a good idea though). Is there a way for me to avoid writing those buddy classes and get the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a partial class. You could directly annotate your model properties. Checkout [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Darin, 
But that's one of the two things i m trying to avoid. 1-writing code is designer generated classes. 2- Making hell a lot of buddy classes as number of my models would probably cross 100 easily. plz suggest some alternate solution where i could avoid these two conditions

Comment: You may take a look at the FluentValidation library (http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It allows you to externalize your validation logic from the models and express it using fluent interfaces. It also has great integration with ASP.NET MVC http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/06/fluentvalidation-1-2-beta-2-and-mvc2-rc2/